# Setting style attributes to an element added via Write()

Tags: javascript

I want the user to see a blueish button with a large text on it, after he presses on an image.
I wrote this code in javascript using the Write() method:

```
<script>
function DoThis()
{
s="<button style=background-color:#aaccdd font-size:50px >Hello</button>";
document.write(s);
}
</script>
```

What I see is only a blue button, but the font size is not changing. I tried to add coma, semicolons etc' but non of it worked. Any Ideas?

Comment: what browser and browser version are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quote for the style tag and semicolon separator:

```
s="<button style=\"background-color:#aaccdd;font-size:50px;\" >Hello</button>";
```

**Edit :**
*The `\` before the semicolon is here to say that the next character in the code (the semicolon) should be considered as part of the current string.*

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to wrap style value in ' or ", try this:

```
<script>
function DoThis()
{
s='<button style="background-color:#aaccdd; font-size:50px;" >Hello</button>';
document.write(s);
}
</script>
```